# Correct htaccess rules for subdomains

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have searched and searched, and tried many solutions but just can't seem to get a handle on the right combination of Apache htaccess magic that works for the following criteria:

I need to be able to recognize and pull a subdomain, as well as the rest of the path info such as:
http://abc.example.com/123 should return the **abc** subdomain as well as the rest of the path, i.e. the **123** subdirectory.

The last portion will always be numeric and the rule should only match in that case. It's always: Any string for the subdomain, my site name, and ends with a numeric subdirectory.

I also need it to work for this case:
http://example.com/profile/123 in which case there is no subdomain, but I need to match only when the site name is followed by 'profile' and again a numeric subdirectory at the end.

And then if these things don't match, drop down into ordinary Apache stuff so I can go to the proper PHP.

I would post the rules I've tried but I've lost them when I opted to write code where I process everything in my own PHP. This works but I know it's horribly inefficient and I'm ready to try again. I'm sure Apache can do this, I just can't get the rules right.

Comment: Show your .htaccess rules you have done.

Comment: To attract good answers it is always best to post what you've attempted. It may not be working but it gives your question more visibility.

Comment: I don't mind going back to what I've tried so I can post it here. But I have a live site right now, so any suggestions on how I can develop this? Or do I just have to use another domain name for testing?